# Custom Extjs 4 proxy for websocket communication

Tags: javascript, extjs4, websocket

I have ExtJS 4 MVC application and websocket channel with Socket.IO as a main transport layer (static files served with nginx and all data communication - via websocket|json|rpc).

So, I want to wrap all proxy requests to my websocket channel. Extjs doesn't have built-in proxy for that.

What is the best way to do it? Create custom proxy class or use existing one (Memory, for example) and intercept request in event handlers?

Comment: AutobahnJS includes an ExtJS 4 proxy for WAMP/WebSocket : https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnJS/tree/master/autobahnextjs

Comment: Ext.ux.data.proxy.WebSocket now available for ExtJS: https://github.com/wilk/Ext.ux.data.proxy.WebSocket